# "Crop" a photo using CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I have a list of items I need to "crop" (I realize that using pure CSS it doesn't really crop just shows you a portion of the image) so far I have it looking like...

This: [My JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/V4YEx/1/)

Basically I am almost there, I just need to center the image in the cropped zone so its showing basically the top middle section.

```
.cocktailThumb img{
border-width:0px;
width:300px;
height:350px;
position:relative;     /Tried adding this
right: 40px;   /Tried adding this
}

.cocktailThumb {
border-width:0px;
width:220px;
height:150px;
padding-left:20px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

The sections I added and tried to change made the image go into the center. But the overflow still went out of the left side whereas I need to to stay contained within the div.

Any help I could get would be awesome, I am fairly new to programming but am enjoying every step of it.

Thanks again!
Pat

Edit: Found the answer was within the clip property. Thanks BrbCoding

Comment: What about the `crop` css property?

Comment: I don't think he needs special cropping so maybe there's no need to use css `crop`

Comment: use css `crop` property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if you just used `background-image` with some background positioning?

HTML

```
<div id="crop"></div>
```

CSS

```
#crop {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/300/300);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/gAH2t/)**

EDIT: Or, you could even use the `clip` property...

```
.cropped {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(75px, 250px, 250px, 75px);
}
```

And here's a demo -- click the image to crop it.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/e5aWr/)**

Comment: +1 for the clip. I see you changed the `rect()`, before one of your 250px was 25px which, oddly, worked in Firefox.  It did what I expected in Chrome (cropped the image completely out).

Comment: ha, that's weird... Yeah I changed the dimensions because I thought it looked kinda wacky. kinda fun problem.

Comment: Not sure, I think it's pretty widely supported. [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip) shows 87.12% support, but you never know how accurate that is. I've tested it in Chrome, Chrome Canary, Firefox, and IE10 -- all of which work.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The clip property worked perfectly once I got a better understanding for it. I wasn't able to do the first way because I wasn't getting my image from the CSS (though I may have been able to do it somehow still) I tried working with background-position but didn't make it to far. Thanks @brbcoding :)

Answer (score 3):

set `max-width: 100%;` to the img

http://jsfiddle.net/V4YEx/3/

Comment: that's a zoom, not a crop?

Comment: it's a crop, it crops off the bottom part

Comment: ok, it's quarter of a crop, but it doesn't help if he wants any of the sides taken off

Answer (score 2):

Negative margins on the `a.darken`:

```
margin-left: -50px;
margin-top: -50px;
height: 200px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V4YEx/7/

Comment: better do that on the overlay too or you'll get 50px of whitespace on the top and bottom during the `:hover` state.

Comment: didn't realise there was a rollover state ^^

Comment: @Chimoo I forgot to mention the rollover state, but thanks for answering :) Its helped me get an even better understanding of things

Answer (score 1):

Use css sprites.

```
background:url(http://www.girlsgetaway.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/drinks_300x350.jpg) -50px -15px;
<img src="" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V4YEx/6/

Comment: Using a background image is a good idea. However, that's not really a sprite. Sprites contain multiple graphics in one image file which can be displayed independently by showing specific parts of the image. http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: Oh ok ok got it, so sprites use background but not same. Thank you sir I will learn about it

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `position: relative` to .cocktailThumb and then add `position: absolute` to the image, you can move it around at will inside of the container.  For instance, if you want it all the way to the right, you can just do `right: 0` on the image.  From here, you can change the right property to whatever you need to center it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V4YEx/1/